# How do you return data with curl

Tags: php, curl

I am new to accepting cURL so I am not sure what is going wrong here this is my code.

**test.php**

```
$curlURL= "http://geo.domain.com/index.php";

$postFields = array(
    'auth' => 'justanauthkey',
    'ip' => '184.71.16.158'
);

$ch = curl_init($curlURL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$curlURL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postFields);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

//$resarray = json_decode($result, true);
echo $result;
```

**index.php that receives the $_POST**

```
if(!empty($_POST)){
    print_r($_POST);
}
```

I am unsure of what to do in the index.php file do I echo out or print_r the array for the curl request to file to process.

Comment: try curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,  http_build_query($postFields));  instead

Comment: Nope that did not work

Comment: I'd investigate the problem using the command-line curl as such:
 curl -v -X POST -d auth=justanauthkey -d ip 184.71.16.158 [url]

Comment: I found it I think, the problem is related to my .htaccess file that is sending everything to the root index.php file and $_POST is not being received.